# JavaScript - get text from text area on another page

Tags: javascript, arrays, xhtml

I want to fill an array by parsing values from a text area, div, etc. on another page on the same site.  (Poor man's database.). It is a hosted site, so all I have is JavaScript, no jquery, much less php, etc.
I can do the parsing, but first I have to be able to get the text from another page within the site.  Is this eve possible in vanilla JavaScript?

Here's the plan.  I set up a data page (so I will know its URL), with a field or div containing the data, formatted so I can parse it.
On entering another page where I need the data, I'll run a JS routine to read the data and fill my JS array.

But I can't figure out how to reference this other page in JS, much less get the contents of an object on it.  The cross-domain security should not be a problem, but the syntax certainly is!

Comment: What about AJAX + JSON? Just out of curiosity, why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: Can you use HTML5 data storage? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Answer (score 1):

How about using IndexedDB. Check it out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB

Answer (score 0):

The answer I came up with involved setting up forms on the data page (one form per DB entry: date, time, content, title, etc). Then on the calling page I create an iframe which displays the datapage. (This iframe is hidden once testing is over.)
I get the BODY content from the iframed document:

```
var iFrame=document.getElementById("iframe_id");
var myDoc;
if (iFrame.contentDocument) myDoc = iFrame.contentDocument; // FF, etc.
else if (iFrame.contentWindow) myDoc = iFrame.contentWindow; // IE
var iFrameBody = myDoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

After that, with the document's body HTML in hand, it's simple enough to find the various forms; each one has the class "dataform", so I just get all elements with class name "dataform", which leads to the individual fields/values on each form. Etc. etc.

Still in development, but the basic procedure works fine, and it's all vanilla JavaScript.